# Nested define doesn't load dependency on localhost

Tags: requirejs

I have the following simple structure:

index.html

```
...
<script src="static/js/lib/require.js" data-main="static/js/main"></script>
</head>
...
```

static/js/main.js

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'static/js',
  paths: {
    m: 'modules'
  }
});

require(['m/test01'], function(test01) {
  console.log(test01.print());
});
```

static/js/modules/test01.js

```
define(['m/test02'], function(test02){
  return {
    print: function() {
      return 'test01 and '+ test02;
    }
  };
});
```

static/js/modules/test02.js

```
define(function() {
  return 'test02';
});
```

Now when I open index.html directly (file:///index.html) all goes well. The script loading works and "test01 and test02" is logged in the console.

However, if I'm opening via xampp (localhost/requiretest/index.html) the loading of test01.js goes well, but for test02.js I get this error in the console (Firefox):

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/01-test-grunt/static/js/test02.js
(removed "http://" before localhost for stackoverflow)
```

As you can see the 'modules/' part is missing in the URL.
Anyone got any idea what might be going on?

NOTE: It does work when I change baseUrl to 'static/js/modules', but I can't do this because of my grunt buildprocess. Anyway, I assume other paths won't be loaded either, so is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: btw it also does not work when using defining a dependency like this ['./test02'] or ['modules/test02']

Comment: possible duplicate of [Require.js loosing url context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724944/require-js-loosing-url-context)